# USB Webcam Problem

Tags: usb, webcam

My webcam is not working properly, i have even put it on a powered hub.
I have a new raspberry pi 4

```
fswebcam -d /dev/video0 image.jpg
--- Opening /dev/video0...
Trying source module v4l2...
/dev/video0 opened.
No input was specified, using the first.
Adjusting resolution from 384x288 to 352x288.
Error starting stream.
VIDIOC_STREAMON: Protocol error
Unable to use mmap. Using read instead.
Unable to use read.

lsusb:
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0c45:6366 Microdia
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

dmesg:
[ 1566.845240] usb 1-1.2.1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 1567.027223] usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0c45, idProduct=6366, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 1567.027239] usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=3
[ 1567.027253] usb 1-1.2.1: Product: AUKEY PC-W1
[ 1567.027265] usb 1-1.2.1: Manufacturer: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
[ 1567.027277] usb 1-1.2.1: SerialNumber: AUKEY PC-W1
[ 1567.030548] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device AUKEY PC-W1 (0c45:6366)
[ 1567.030559] uvcvideo: Forcing device quirks to 0x100 by module parameter for testing purpose.
[ 1567.030569] uvcvideo: Please report required quirks to the linux-uvc-devel mailing list.
[ 1567.049096] uvcvideo 1-1.2.1:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[ 1567.049113] uvcvideo 1-1.2.1:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 3 was not initialized!
[ 1567.049128] uvcvideo 1-1.2.1:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[ 1567.049143] uvcvideo 1-1.2.1:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[ 1567.049513] input: AUKEY PC-W1: AUKEY PC-W1 as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.1/1-1.2.1:1.0/input/input2
[ 1567.092967] usb 1-1.2.1: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84

v4l2-ctl --list-devices
bcm2835-codec-decode (platform:bcm2835-codec):
        /dev/video10
        /dev/video11
        /dev/video12

AUKEY PC-W1: AUKEY PC-W1 (usb-0000:01:00.0-1.2.1):
        /dev/video0
        /dev/video1
```

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=183599 - the comment in the second last post implies /dev/video1 will work

Comment: Have you made sure that your USB webcam is compatible with the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Hello and welcome -- What's the output of `ls /dev/video*`? Check it out: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303772/163862

Comment: using /dev/video1 did not work:  Trying source module v4l2...
/dev/video1 opened.
No input was specified, using the first.
Unable to query input 0.
VIDIOC_ENUMINPUT: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Comment: ls /dev/video* gives: /dev/video0  /dev/video1  /dev/video10  /dev/video11  /dev/video12

Comment: driver links seem there: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar  1 13:21 /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.2.1:1.0/driver -> ../../../../../../../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/uvcvideo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar  2 17:38 /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.2.1:1.1/driver -> ../../../../../../../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/uvcvideo